# angularjs - combine data from for loop api calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, api

I have this API that has pages 1-10 and I want to loop through the page numbers to make the API calls

```
app.factory('companies', ['$http', function($http) {
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        var data = $http.get('https://examplepage.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?per_page=50&page=' + i);
        console.log('list', data);
    }
    return data;
}]);
```

This is what I get when I console log the data for all 10 API calls
[JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df8W8.png)

[image]

My attempt to display all of the data (list of names), but it seems as though it's only taking the last API call and displaying it. How do I combine all of the returned data into one object to display the list of name from pages 1-10?

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'companies', function($scope, companies) {
    companies.success(function(data) {
        $scope.companies = data;
        console.log('companies', $scope.companies);
    });
}]);
```

view.html

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="HomeController">
        <div ng-repeat="company in companies" class="list">
            <a href="#/{{ company.id }}" class="company-name">{{ company.name }}</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `.success` method is [deprecated and been removed from V1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Answer (score 1):

Each call to the $http service returns a promise. You need to use `$q.all` to consolidate the promises:

```
app.factory('companies', function($http,$q) {
    return { tenPagesPromise: tenPagesPromise };

    function tenPagesPromise () {
        var indices = Array.from({length:10}).map((x,i)=>i);
        var promises = indices.map(i=>pagePromise(i));
        return $q.all(promises).then(responseArray => {
            var dataArray = responseArray.map(x=>x.data);
            return dataArray.reduce((t,x)=>t.concat(x),[]);
        });
    }

    function pagePromise(i) {
        var url = "https://examplepage.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories";
        var params = { per_page: 50, page: i };
        var config = { params: params }
        promise = $http.get(url,config);
        return promise;
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
companies.tenPagesPromise.then(data => {
    $scope.companies = data;
}).catch(function(errorResponse) {
    console.log(errorResponse);
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve the promise and then add the data to an array, something like this:

```
app.factory('companies', ['$http', function($http) {
    data = []
    for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        $http.get('https://examplepage.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?per_page=50&page=' + i)
          .then( function(resp) {
             console.log(resp.data);
             data.push(resp.data);
           })
    }
    return data;
}]);
```